# Issue installing PAR::Packer with strawberry Perl

Tags: perl, strawberry-perl

I'm struggling for two days now to get the PAR::Packer module installed. I'm new to CPAN, and this is the first module I want to install, so I first thought it is me. But I reinstalled strawberry Perl a few times now and also used an older versions. The installation always fails with:

windres: unexpected version string length 68 != 32 + 8

I found a few hits on this string and it appears to be an issue with MingW (whatever this is):

http://mingw.5.n7.nabble.com/Wine-crosstest-build-fails-with-quot-unexpected-version-string-length-68-32-8-quot-td29953.html#a29975

But I do not know how to get this patch and how to install it.

Below the hole capture of the installation:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\shepp>cpan PAR::Packer CPAN: CPAN::SQLite
loaded ok (v0.202) Database was generated on Tue, 27 Nov 2012 20:58:53
GMT Running install for module 'PAR::Packer' Running make for
R/RS/RSCHUPP/PAR-Packer-1.013.tar.gz CPAN: LWP::UserAgent loaded ok
(v6.04) CPAN: Time::HiRes loaded ok (v1.9725) Fetching with LWP:
http://cpan.strawberryperl.com/authors/id/R/RS/RSCHUPP/PAR-Packer-1.013.tar.gz
CPAN: YAML::XS loaded ok (v0.38) CPAN: Digest::SHA loaded ok (v5.72)
Fetching with LWP:
http://cpan.strawberryperl.com/authors/id/R/RS/RSCHUPP/CHECKSUMS CPAN:
Compress::Zlib loaded ok (v2.055) Checksum for
C:\strawberry\cpan\sources\authors\id\R\RS\RSCHUPP\PAR-Packer-1.013
.tar.gz ok CPAN: Archive::Tar loaded ok (v1.90) CPAN: File::Temp
loaded ok (v0.22) CPAN: Parse::CPAN::Meta loaded ok (v1.4404) CPAN:
CPAN::Meta loaded ok (v2.120921) CPAN: Module::CoreList loaded ok
(v2.74)

  CPAN.pm: Building R/RS/RSCHUPP/PAR-Packer-1.013.tar.gz

Checking if your kit is complete... Looks good Warning: prerequisite
Getopt::ArgvFile 1.07 not found. Warning: prerequisite
Module::ScanDeps 1.05 not found. Prototype mismatch: sub main::prompt:
none vs ($;$) at C:/strawberry/perl/lib/Ex tUtils/MakeMaker.pm line
219. Writing Makefile for par.exe Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json Writing Makefile for PAR::Packer Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
---- Unsatisfied dependencies detected during ----
----      RSCHUPP/PAR-Packer-1.013.tar.gz     ----
    Getopt::ArgvFile [requires]
    Module::ScanDeps [requires] Running make test   Delayed until after prerequisites Running make install   Delayed until after
prerequisites Running install for module 'Getopt::ArgvFile' Running
make for J/JS/JSTENZEL/Getopt-ArgvFile-1.11.tar.gz Fetching with LWP:
http://cpan.strawberryperl.com/authors/id/J/JS/JSTENZEL/Getopt-ArgvFile-1.11.tar
.gz Fetching with LWP:
http://cpan.strawberryperl.com/authors/id/J/JS/JSTENZEL/CHECKSUMS
Checksum for
C:\strawberry\cpan\sources\authors\id\J\JS\JSTENZEL\Getopt-ArgvFile
-1.11.tar.gz ok

  CPAN.pm: Building J/JS/JSTENZEL/Getopt-ArgvFile-1.11.tar.gz

Checking if your kit is complete... Looks good Writing Makefile for
Getopt::ArgvFile Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json cp ArgvFile.pm
blib\lib\Getopt\ArgvFile.pm   JSTENZEL/Getopt-ArgvFile-1.11.tar.gz  
C:\strawberry\c\bin\dmake.exe -- OK Running make test
C:\strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-e"
"test_harness(0, 'blib\lib', 'blib\arch')" t/*.t t/base.t ...........
ok t/expandenv.t ...... ok t/fileopt.t ........ ok t/noHOMEvar.t
...... ok t/pod-coverage.t ... skipped: Test::Pod::Coverage 1.00
required for testing POD coverage t/pod.t ............ skipped:
Test::Pod 1.00 required for testing POD t/prefix.t ......... ok
t/resolvepathes.t .. ok t/use1.t ........... ok t/use2.t ...........
ok All tests successful. Files=10, Tests=43,  3 wallclock secs ( 0.08
usr +  0.09 sys =  0.17 CPU) Result: PASS  
JSTENZEL/Getopt-ArgvFile-1.11.tar.gz   C:\strawberry\c\bin\dmake.exe
test -- OK Running make install Installing
C:\strawberry\perl\site\lib\Getopt\ArgvFile.pm Appending installation
info to C:\strawberry\perl\lib/perllocal.pod  
JSTENZEL/Getopt-ArgvFile-1.11.tar.gz   C:\strawberry\c\bin\dmake.exe
install UNINST=1 -- OK Running install for module 'Module::ScanDeps'
Running make for R/RS/RSCHUPP/Module-ScanDeps-1.10.tar.gz Fetching
with LWP:
http://cpan.strawberryperl.com/authors/id/R/RS/RSCHUPP/Module-ScanDeps-1.10.tar.
gz Checksum for
C:\strawberry\cpan\sources\authors\id\R\RS\RSCHUPP\Module-ScanDeps-
1.10.tar.gz ok

  CPAN.pm: Building R/RS/RSCHUPP/Module-ScanDeps-1.10.tar.gz

Checking if your kit is complete... Looks good Writing Makefile for
Module::ScanDeps Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json cp
lib/Module/ScanDeps/Cache.pm blib\lib\Module\ScanDeps\Cache.pm cp
lib/Module/ScanDeps/DataFeed.pm blib\lib\Module\ScanDeps\DataFeed.pm
cp lib/Module/ScanDeps.pm blib\lib\Module\ScanDeps.pm
C:\strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe "-Iinc" -MExtUtils::Command -e cp --
script/scan deps.pl blib\script\scandeps.pl pl2bat.bat
blib\script\scandeps.pl   RSCHUPP/Module-ScanDeps-1.10.tar.gz  
C:\strawberry\c\bin\dmake.exe -- OK Running make test
C:\strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-e"
"test_harness(0, 'inc', 'blib\lib', 'blib\arch')" t/*.t t/0-pod.t
....................................... skipped: Test::Pod 1.00 requir
ed for testing POD t/1-static_functional_interface_real.t ..........
ok t/10-case-insensitive-keys.t .................... ok
t/12-ScanFileRE.t ............................... ok
t/13-static_prefork_test.t ...................... skipped: This test
requires pr efork.pm which is not installed. Skipping.
t/14-scan_chunk.t ............................... ok
t/14-static_functional_cached.t ................. 1/? 0 Couldn't
retrieve data from file deps_cache.dat. Building new cache.
t/14-static_functional_cached.t ................. ok t/16-scan_line.t
................................ ok t/17-private_methods.t
.......................... ok t/2-static_functional_interface_fake.t
.......... ok t/3-static_oo_interface_real.t .................. ok
t/4-static_functional_interface_options_fake.t .. ok
t/5-pluggable_fake.t ............................ ok t/6-file-glob.t
................................. ok t/7-check-dynaloader.t
.......................... # dynamic modules used for tes t: Cwd
File::Glob Data::Dumper List::Util Time::HiRes Compress::Raw::Zlib
t/7-check-dynaloader.t .......................... 1/36
C:\DOCUME~1\shepp\LOCALS~ 1\Temp\5xtWJc0E06 syntax OK
C:\DOCUME~1\shepp\LOCALS~1\Temp\JzIXUYCKFa syntax OK
t/7-check-dynaloader.t .......................... 11/36
C:\DOCUME~1\shepp\LOCALS ~1\Temp\jGWh6j7CQ_ syntax OK
C:\DOCUME~1\shepp\LOCALS~1\Temp\vHQnTPJrl3 syntax OK
t/7-check-dynaloader.t .......................... 21/36
C:\DOCUME~1\shepp\LOCALS ~1\Temp\4nv64Rabo3 syntax OK
t/7-check-dynaloader.t .......................... 29/36
C:\DOCUME~1\shepp\LOCALS ~1\Temp\tX8ukeJjGy syntax OK
t/7-check-dynaloader.t .......................... ok
t/8-check_duplicated_entries.t .................. ok
t/9-check_path_to_inc_name.t .................... ok All tests
successful. Files=17, Tests=17352, 67 wallclock secs ( 1.89 usr + 
0.22 sys =  2.11 CPU) Result: PASS   RSCHUPP/Module-ScanDeps-1.10.tar.gz   C:\strawberry\c\bin\dmake.exe
test -- OK Running make install Installing
C:\strawberry\perl\site\lib\Module\ScanDeps.pm Installing
C:\strawberry\perl\site\lib\Module\ScanDeps\Cache.pm Installing
C:\strawberry\perl\site\lib\Module\ScanDeps\DataFeed.pm Installing
C:\strawberry\perl\site\bin\scandeps.bat Installing
C:\strawberry\perl\site\bin\scandeps.pl Appending installation info to
C:\strawberry\perl\lib/perllocal.pod  
RSCHUPP/Module-ScanDeps-1.10.tar.gz   C:\strawberry\c\bin\dmake.exe
install UNINST=1 -- OK Running make for
R/RS/RSCHUPP/PAR-Packer-1.013.tar.gz   Has already been unwrapped into
directory C:\strawberry\cpan\build\PAR-Packer-
1.013-PEitq2

  CPAN.pm: Building R/RS/RSCHUPP/PAR-Packer-1.013.tar.gz

cp lib/App/Packer/PAR.pm blib\lib\App\Packer\PAR.pm cp
lib/PAR/Packer.pm blib\lib\PAR\Packer.pm cp
lib/PAR/Filter/Obfuscate.pm blib\lib\PAR\Filter\Obfuscate.pm cp
lib/PAR/Filter/PodStrip.pm blib\lib\PAR\Filter\PodStrip.pm cp
lib/PAR/StrippedPARL/Base.pm blib\lib\PAR\StrippedPARL\Base.pm cp
lib/PAR/Filter.pm blib\lib\PAR\Filter.pm cp
lib/PAR/Filter/PatchContent.pm blib\lib\PAR\Filter\PatchContent.pm cp
lib/PAR/Filter/Bytecode.pm blib\lib\PAR\Filter\Bytecode.pm cp
lib/pp.pm blib\lib\pp.pm cp lib/PAR/Filter/Bleach.pm
blib\lib\PAR\Filter\Bleach.pm C:\strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe
file2c.pl -s ..\script\par.pl my_par_pl.c load_m y_par_pl
C:\strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe sha1.c.PL gcc -c -s -O2 -DWIN32 
-DPERL_TEXTMODE_SCRIPTS -DPERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT -DPERL_IM PLICIT_SYS -fno-strict-aliasing -mms-bitfields  -I"C:\strawberry\perl\lib\CORE"  -DLOAD_MY_LIBGCC -DPARL_EXE=\"parl.exe\" -s -O2 main.c windres -F pei-i386 -i winres\pp.rc -o winres\pp.res windres -o ppresource.coff
winres\pp.res windres: unexpected version string length 68 != 32 + 8
dmake:  Error code 129, while making 'ppresource.coff' dmake.exe: 
Error code 255, while making 'subdirs'  
RSCHUPP/PAR-Packer-1.013.tar.gz   C:\strawberry\c\bin\dmake.exe -- NOT
OK Running make test   Can't test without successful make Running make
install   Make had returned bad status, install seems impossible
Stopping: 'install' failed for 'R/RS/RSCHUPP/PAR-Packer-1.013.tar.gz'.
```

Comment: MingW is likely the C compiler used (but I have not checked this).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got it working using the patched version of PAR:Packer :

http://strawberryperl.com/package/kmx/perl-modules-patched/PAR-Packer-1.013_patched.tar.gz

Thanks
Siegfried

Answer (score 2):

[Bug #77408 for PAR-Packer: Cannot build on Win64/Perl64](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=77408)

update: Strawberryperl/Dwimperl uses the MinGW compiler, and the above bug report includes a patch for this issue